# React, Formik, Yup: How to register touch when using calendar picker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I'm new to all three technologies and searched for an answer, but couldn't find one. Note: I simplified the file to make it easier to parse through while you read it, hopefully I didn't cut anything important for debugging.

**I would like to have my form register as touched when a user clicks to select the date using the calendar picker.  Currently I can display the error in the helperText, but it does not alter the style of the form in the same way as it will if the user clicks in the field as though they intend to type it in themselves.**

```
import React, { FC, useRef } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "formik-material-ui-pickers";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import moment from "moment";
import { ReportConfig } from "../ReportConfig";

export type DProps = {
  type: Type | null,
  currentConfig: ReportConfig | null,
};

export const Dialog: FC<DProps> = ({ currentConfig }) => {
  const form: any = useRef(null); // Reference to formik form

  let initialValues = {
    periodStart: moment(currentConfig?.periodStart),
    periodEnd: moment(currentConfig?.periodEnd),
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      innerRef={form}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        periodStart: Yup.date()
          .typeError("Enter a valid date.")
          .max(Yup.ref("periodEnd"), "Must be before End.")
          .required("Required"),
        periodEnd: Yup.date()
          .typeError("Enter a valid date.")
          .min(Yup.ref("periodStart"), "Must be after Start.")
          .required("Required"),
      })}
    >
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleBlur }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field
            variant="inline"
            autoOk
            name={"periodStart"}
            value={values.periodStart}
            label="Start Date"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            component={KeyboardDatePicker}
            format="MM/DD/YYYY"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            error={touched.periodEnd && errors.periodStart !== undefined}
            helperText={errors.periodStart}
          />
          <Field
            variant="inline"
            autoOk
            name={"periodEnd"}
            value={values.periodEnd}
            label="End Date"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            component={KeyboardDatePicker}
            format="MM/DD/YYYY"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            error={touched.periodEnd && errors.periodEnd !== undefined}
            helperText={errors.periodEnd}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

[image: Currently displays this way when date error happens, but user used calendar to select the date]
vs
[image: Should display this way regardless of method used to input date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  You have to add setFieldTouched and give it an anonymous function that sets touched to true.

```
import React, { FC, useRef } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "formik-material-ui-pickers";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import moment from "moment";
import { ReportConfig } from "../ReportConfig";

export type DProps = {
  type: Type | null,
  currentConfig: ReportConfig | null,
};

export const Dialog: FC<DProps> = ({ currentConfig }) => {
  const form: any = useRef(null); // Reference to formik form

  let initialValues = {
    periodStart: moment(currentConfig?.periodStart),
    periodEnd: moment(currentConfig?.periodEnd),
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      innerRef={form}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        periodStart: Yup.date()
          .typeError("Enter a valid date.")
          .max(Yup.ref("periodEnd"), "Must be before End.")
          .required("Required"),
        periodEnd: Yup.date()
          .typeError("Enter a valid date.")
          .min(Yup.ref("periodStart"), "Must be after Start.")
          .required("Required"),
      })}
    >
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleBlur, setFieldTouched }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field
            variant="inline"
            autoOk
            name={"periodStart"}
            value={values.periodStart}
            label="Start Date"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            component={KeyboardDatePicker}
            format="MM/DD/YYYY"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            error={touched.periodEnd && errors.periodStart !== undefined}
            helperText={errors.periodStart}
            onClick={() => setFieldTouched("periodStart", true)}
          />
          <Field
            variant="inline"
            autoOk
            name={"periodEnd"}
            value={values.periodEnd}
            label="End Date"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            component={KeyboardDatePicker}
            format="MM/DD/YYYY"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            error={touched.periodEnd && errors.periodEnd !== undefined}
            helperText={errors.periodEnd}
            onClick={() => setFieldTouched("periodEnd", true)}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```